# Import Data from a XLS online source into Databricks directly

Tags: azure-databricks

I have a XLS file that is hosted online and it keeps getting updated every week. The URL doesn't change. I want to eliminate human effort of downloading the file and uploading it to Databricks.

I want to ingest the data from that online XLS file (on a scheduled basis) into Databricks as a delta table.

What is the best way to approach this?

Additional Information
Using Azure Databricks
The online published XLS file is not password protected or anything so no authentication involved

I have been doing some research and everything shows the use cases of users uploading a xls file from local machine into DBFS which is not what I am looking for.
I want to extract the data from the online URL directly. If I need to store/convert it into DBFS that is acceptable too. I want to set up automation and not have to go about it manually.

Answer (score 0):

> If I need to store/convert it into DBFS that is acceptable too

As per this [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/files/download-internet-files) you can store the file from your url to DBFS like below.

```
import urllib
urllib.request.urlretrieve(<your url>, "/<dbfs-path>filename.xlsx")
```

**My Sample:**

[image]

[image]

After storing it in dbfs, you can ingest it in delta table using spark dataframes and scheduling of the notebooks.